# Установить битрейт аудио потока html

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio

Как можно с помощью тега audio установить битрейт звука (к примеру 128 кб/с)? Или с помощью других инструментов, главное, чтобы звук, который в прямом эфире проигрывается через тег audio, имел такой битрейт, который мне хочется. Спасибо.

Comment: Это определяется на стороне бекенда, что бекенд отдает то браузер и будет проигрывать. Можно в гет параметры адреса добавить требуемый битрейт и сделать чтобы бекенд на это реагировал.

Comment: Еще есть вариант с использованием какой-то библиотеки для преобразования аудио.

Comment: Это все, конечно, хорошо, но аудио ведётся в прямом эфире с адреса, который предоставляет радиостанция, к бекенду которой я напрямую не имею доступа. Если в этом случае никак через фронтенд, то единственный выход - сказать об этом самой радиостанции, чтобы поставили нужный битрейт?

Comment: А какую цель вы преследуете? Уменьшение трафика?

Comment: Да. Часто звук подлагивает, просто не воспроизводится. Как сказали на самом радио, это из-за высокого битрейта и из-за того, что слушают много человек. Поэтому и хочется уменьшить качество звука.

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл решать проблему там где она создается, уменьшить битрейт и расширить канал радио.